# Cannot configure jQuery datepicker to select default date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the following plugin for a datepicker:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

This is a very nice plugin however I am finding it difficult to set a default date when loading the box.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVk7W/).

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Box 1 contains 25/12/2013.  I want the datepicker to default to this date when the user selects this box.  Box 2 contains nothing therefore the box should default to today.

**NB** This is currently using standard jquery-ui-datepicker.

I have tried setting various options with no success.  I have also tried to read where the value is being set but again cannot see where the input is referenced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
                .filter('[value!=""]')
                .datepicker('setDate', '12/25/13');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVk7W/1/)

As a sidenote you can set a defaultDate to any datepicker that is submitted if the user doesn't select a date, but that date is not shown as the value of the input

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
                .filter('[value!=""]')
                .datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", '12/25/13' );
```

Comment: OK but how do I pass the contents of the current input dynamically?

Comment: I see you have hard coded the date in the setDate function.  What if the contents of the input with the .datepicker class had for example '01/01/2012'.  The datepicker needs to load dynamically to the contents of the input

Comment: That's not a valid format for the date, do you wish to set the datepicker to that format, as in `DD/MM/YYYY` ?

Comment: Yes, this is working for this plugin but not for the one in the question. http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Well, they are completely different plugins with completely different options, and it did seem a little strange to ask a question about one datepicker, and then base the code on another datepicker, but I assumed you where looking for answers regarding the jQuery datepicker

Comment: Sorry it was noted that the plugin in the fiddle was just merely an example. I should have explained this further

Comment: Is it achievable do you think?

Comment: It probably is, it looks like the datetimepicker gets the value from the element automatically, so all you have to do is set the value to something like `2014/03/15 05:06` and it should work ?

Answer (score 0):

In your original question you say you're using third party datepicker plugin, but in your fiddle you're using JQueryUI DatePicker. So here's an example for JQueryUI datepicker.
I'm sure it can be easily updated for the third party plugin.

Try this:

HTML:

```
Box 1
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="25/12/2013" />

Box 2
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value=""/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(index){
    var dateStr = $(this).attr("value");
    var date=new Date();

    if(dateStr.length>0)
        date=$.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", dateStr);

    $(this).datepicker({defaultDate:date});
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVk7W/3/